# Select All Check Boxes (Two sepereate groups of check boxes)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using the below code to select/deselect all check boxes on a page. The page started with only one group of check boxes on the page with the class `"allowedphrases"`. The page now contains two seperate lists of check boxes: one for `"allowedphrases"` and a new one for `"bannedphrases"`.

I want to have two seperate `"Select all"` check boxes on my page:

- one to `"select_all_allowed"` (checks all the check boxes with class `"allowedphrases"`)
- one to `"select_all_banned"` (checks all the check boxes with class `"bannedphrases"`).

How could I edit my below code to include this other set of check boxes? At the moment it works for `"allowedphrases"` only.

```
<SCRIPT>
var select_all = document.getElementById("select_all_allowed"); //select all checkbox
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("allowedphrases");
//checkbox items

//select all checkboxes
select_all.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = select_all.checked;
}
});


for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){ //".allowedphrases" change
    //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
    if(this.checked == false){
        select_all.checked = false;
    }
    //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
    if(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked').length == checkboxes.length){
        select_all.checked = true;
    }
});
}
</SCRIPT>
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Ids[]" value="MYVALUE" class="bannedphrases">
<input type="checkbox" name="Ids[]" value="MYVALUE" class="allowedphrases">
<div><input type="checkbox" id="select_all_allowed"> Select All Allowed</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="select_all_banned"> Select All Banned</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I only see your old code. Try setting a special class to each set of checkboxes, like you do with `allowedphrases` className.

Comment: not clear what you intend to. I see class-names in the code different from those you stated in your explanation. So, kindly, providing more explanation would help as well as your HTML code.

Comment: I've edited my post with the html for the check boxes and the select all check boxs. I basically want to click the select all allowed box and have all the check boxes with the class allowedphrases. then have the same happen for select all banned and banned phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

According to your wish: in the case if one of phrases checkboxes is deselected then the control select checkbox will be deselected too. If all of phrases checkboxes are selected then the control select checkbox will be selected too.

```js
var select_all_allowed = document.getElementById('select_all_allowed'),
    select_all_banned = document.getElementById('select_all_banned'),
    allowedphrases = document.querySelectorAll('.allowedphrases'),
    bannedphrases = document.querySelectorAll('.bannedphrases');

function check(arPhrases, objSelect)
{
    var areAllChecked = true,
        i = arPhrases.length;

    while(i--)
        //uncheck 'select all', if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if(!arPhrases[i].checked)
        {
            areAllChecked = false;
            break
        }

    objSelect.checked = areAllChecked;
}

select_all_allowed.addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
   for(var i = allowedphrases.length; i--;)
        allowedphrases[i].checked = this.checked;
});

select_all_banned.addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
   for(var i = bannedphrases.length; i--;)
        bannedphrases[i].checked = this.checked;
});

for(var i = allowedphrases.length; i--;)
{
    allowedphrases[i].addEventListener('change', function(e)
    {
        check(allowedphrases, select_all_allowed);
    });
}

for(i = bannedphrases.length; i--;)
{
    bannedphrases[i].addEventListener('change', function(e)
    {
        check(bannedphrases, select_all_banned);
    });
}
```

```css
label{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Allowed phrases</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" class="allowedphrases">
        <input type="checkbox" class="allowedphrases">
        <input type="checkbox" class="allowedphrases">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Banned phrases</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" class="bannedphrases">
        <input type="checkbox" class="bannedphrases">
        <input type="checkbox" class="bannedphrases">
    </fieldset>    
</div>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="select_all_allowed">Select all allowed</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="select_all_banned">Select all banned</label>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'm definitely going to have to pick the code apart and learn whats going on. Thanks for the point in the right direction.